# VirtualBox won't open in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I installed VirtualBox from a deb file. The link to that file is below.

[https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.34/virtualbox-6.1_6.1.34-150636.1~Debian~bullseye_amd64.deb](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.34/virtualbox-6.1_6.1.34-150636.1%7EDebian%7Ebullseye_amd64.deb)

I used the following command to install the deb file:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

After the installation was complete, I moved VirtualBox to my desktop and double clicked on it, but nothing happened. I waited a minute or two then double clicked on it again. Still, nothing happened. Did I install the package incorrectly, or is my particular version of VirtualBox not supported on my current OS?

My Linux Mint details are below:

[image: Details]

Comment: The one you need is here: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.34/virtualbox-6.1_6.1.34-150636.1~Ubuntu~eoan_amd64.deb. LM 20.x is based on Ubuntu 20.04, not Debian 11.

Comment: Thank you, but that is odd. That deb package worked last time.

Comment: Maybe you got lucky last time. The installation procedure for LM 20.x is outlined in detail here: https://linuxhint.com/install-virtualbox-linux-mint/. I would suggest adding the Oracle repo so that the updates will come as you update your system,

Comment: How do you add the Oracle repository if you don't mind?

Comment: Never mind. It works fine.